# using full zend query in while loop.And in loop i execute full query and merge them in one array

Tags: php, zend-framework, open-source

optimize the zend query takes too much time to execute. using full zend query in while loop.And  in loop i execute full query and merge them in one array .. at the i have one array with results BUT takes too much time to execute .. below is exact case

```
while($str){
    $db = Zend_Registry::get('dbadapter');
    $select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);    
    $select = $db->select();

    // my business logic omitted 

    $stmt = $select->query();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    // after execution merge the record in new array ( $final_result )
    $temp_arr =  $result;
    $final_result = array_merge($final_result,$temp_arr);
    unset($temp_arr);
}
```

Comment: What is $str by the way.....?????

Comment: You've said that running the query takes too long, but you've omitted the actual query that you're executing.  Can you please edit in the **real, actual code** that you're using?

Comment: Not surprising that code segment featuring a query in a loop is taking a long time to execute.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to write following code inside the loop, Write them outside the loop...

```
$db = Zend_Registry::get('dbadapter');
$select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);  
$select = $db->select();
$stmt = $select->query();
```

Then write following code inside the loop:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$final_result[] = $result;

unset($result);
```

This Code might help you.......

Comment: and if I'm not wrong "$select = new Zend_Db_Select($db)" and "$select = $db->select();" are doing the same thing.